# Ошибка в методе cv2.ANN_MLP() Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Здравствуйте. При попытке выполнить такой код

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
class NeuralNetwork(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = cv2.ANN_MLP()

    def create(self):
        layer_size = np.int32([38400, 32, 4])
        self.model.create(layer_size)
        self.model.load('mlp_xml/mlp.xml')

    def predict(self, samples):
        ret, resp = self.model.predict(samples)
        return resp.argmax(-1)

model = NeuralNetwork()
model.create()
```

Получаю ошибку

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ANN_MLP'

Пробовал менять `cv2.ANN_MLP()` на `cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()`, но не помогло.

Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Укажите вашу версию OpenCV. В своем OpenCV 3.0 я не смог найти метода load, но он у меня старенький и из разряда тестовых версий. Но вот есть [пример кода](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/opencv-3.2.0.tar.gz/opencv-3.2.0/samples/python/letter_recog.py) для 3.2, в котором `load` в наличии. Все, что могу сказать - метод `create` замените на `setLayerSizes` и все обхекты переехали в модуль `ml`, поэтому вариант `cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()` верен для 3 версии.

Comment: В догонку: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5891, http://answers.opencv.org/question/75077/opencv-300-python-svmload-is-missing/ - судя по всему, данный метод (`load`) забыли приложить и вроде в 3.2 проблема была решена.